# Problem with iphone/sqlite

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I am trying to update from internet my sqlite content.
I have copied the sqlite db to documents directory, and from there I use an ASIHTTPRequest to get the textual sqlite updates (ready sqlite statements with values and keys).

my sqlite statement is as follows:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO items (id, name, parentid, orderme) VALUES (...);
```

The ids on the remote sqlite (the one I get the statements from) are 1:1 with those in my local project.

The update though, only occurs on the already found ids. When there is no Id found there is no insert happening. Is there a problem in the sqlite iphone version?

Now what is weird is that if I run the same command from inside the app (and not receiving from internet), it creates the required data. I have tried it with both fmdb and sqlite native commands so there must be something wrong with the inserting of the code. Do you have any insights on this?

(I don't use core data for some portability reasons).

Comment: the sql query looks perfectly fine, how about the obj c part of it? (I have identical sql to that in the app store currently)

Comment: can you clarify one thing: you said the remote data is 1:1 with your local data, so shouldn't every row have an existing ID, and therefore, you wouldn't have any INSERTs going on, just REPLACEs? How is the data being returned from your service, perhaps it's only returning existing rows, so you're just not seeing any insertion opportunities? have you logged the data before you try to update your DB?

Comment: No, as I answered below, it was actually a one line script error. I tried to pack all the inserts(replaces) so that I would not have large blocks ("name" is a large text field). 

It's funny how little things like that can get you delay on the development.

Answer (score 0):

So, actually the scripts were fine.

What SQLITE does not support is multiple commands in one line (like MySQL does). So once I broke them down to multiple lines everything worked fine.